# What does "悠" mean in "悠久"?

Tags: adverbs

"悠久" is often used to describe a period of history (I read it from ), and I wonder how does the adv "悠" work in "悠久".

I've searched, the complete word means,

> 悠久，汉语词汇，形容词（褒义）。
>   拼音：yōu jiǔ
>   词义：长久；久远。

But I can't figure out what does "悠" mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`悠` has the same meaning as `久` in this case.

It is a kind of word making method in Chinese, which combines two synonymic characters together. Perhaps the terminology `tautology` can be used here.

For example: `亲吻 拥抱 战斗 早晨 林木`

Comment: Yip Po-ching CLCS uses the term juxtapositional （not accepted by US(?) spellcheck）type V-V:亲吻、拥抱，N-N： 战斗、早晨、林木， Chinese term 并列

Comment: @user6065 Thanks for your correction. And `战斗` is either V-V or N-N, as verb or noun should be decided depending on the context.